# Grep list for text with 2 numbers and 2 letters

Tags: grep

I have a list of HEX numbers from 0000 to FFFF.

I am trying to parse the list to only include text with 2 numbers 0-9 and 2 letters A-F, but am having no luck.  I have been trying `egrep -v [0-9]{3}` and outputting the results to a file thinking that would find any entry without 3 numbers and then taking that file and doing `egrep -v [0-9]{4}` against the out from the previous command, but this isn't working as I still have entries with 3 and 4 numbers.  I was planning on also running `egrep -v [A-F]{3}` and `egrep -v [A-F]{4}` to filter the rest but it is still not working.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file like the following

```
~$ cat Patterns.txt 
[0-9][0-9][A-F][A-F]
[0-9][A-F][0-9][A-F]
[0-9][A-F][A-F][0-9]
[A-F][A-F][0-9][0-9]
[A-F][0-9][A-F][0-9]
[A-F][0-9][0-9][A-F]
~$
```

This is the sample input

```
~$ cat HEX.txt 
FFFF
08FF
F0AA
FF08
0F0F
F0F0
~$
```

And this is the sample output

```
~$ grep -f Patterns.txt HEX.txt 
08FF
FF08
0F0F
F0F0
```

**Explanation:**

There can be only 6 possible combinations in your case

```
Number, Number, Letter, Letter
Number, Letter, Number, Letter
Number, Letter, Letter, Number
Letter, Letter, Number, Number
Letter, Number, Letter, Number
Letter, Number, Letter, Letter
```

We are storing all these combinations in `Patterns.txt` and asking grep to use those patterns to find values from `HEX.txt`